# Automatically log onto a site at a specific time

Tags: windows-7, login, scheduled-tasks

Is there any software (freeware) which will automate tasks on my system, so it can be used to log in or log off any site at specific time?

I had a software called **Robotask** but couldn't understand how it works.

Comment: Very interesting question, why people downvote it? I'd like to add, is there a service? Could it be made with IFTTT? For instance, login even when I don't run the script, because I don't have my phone or computer, and I want to keep a site streak.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can definitely use Windows PowerShell for this purpose. Granted, you'll have to get used to writing some code, but you can automate Internet Explorer via the IE COM API. Here's a short example to get you started:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application;
$ie.Visible = $true;
$ie.Navigate("www.google.com");

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1;

$myinput = $ie.Document.getElementById('lst-ib');
$myinput.value = "powershell";

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1;

$myform = $ie.Document.getElementById('tsf');
$myform.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to improve the way the browser waits for page load, or  you have any side effects from the valuechange you need to trigger in Javascript, then you should download a module we made for making IE automation simpler (it's free):

http://autobrowse.start-automating.com

To do the above, it would be:

```
Open-Browser -Url "http://www.google.com" | 
    Set-BrowserControl -Id lst-ib -Value powershell | 
    Set-BrowserControl -Id tsf -click
```

Hope this Helps